# React ignores 'for' attribute of the label element

Tags: reactjs, label

In React (Facebook's framework), I need to render a label element bound to a text input using the standard `for` attribute.

e.g. the following JSX is used:

```
<label for="test">Test</label>
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

However, this produces HTML missing the required (and standard) `for` attribute:

```
<label>Test</label>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 777, accepted):

The `for` attribute is called `htmlFor` for consistency with the DOM property API. If you're using the development build of React, you should have seen a warning in your console about this.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Could you explain "for consistency with the DOM API" for me?

Comment: If you have a `label` element (as returned by `document.createElement`, `document.getElementById`, etc) you'd access its `for` property as `label.htmlFor`.

Comment: In React, is there any way to link a label to an input without id? If I use ID and re-use a component, it ends up for the page having multiple inputs with the same id.

Comment: @Meglio In HTML you need a ID for the for attribute to work. To make your component reusable you could add a name property to your component that you set as ID and as name attribute on the actual input field.

Comment: @WimMostmans what if I don't have a unique name property? What is a safe way to generate unique IDs? Maybe a class variable that gets incremented each time it's used? Can't I just ask React for the ID of the current component? It surely has one.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/N-gDqH2LEcQ/bjBBTKSAZaYJ). They say to use an ID generator.

Comment: @BenAlpert Thanks for shedding light on that. I never used to look at the DOM API becuase of jQuery and stuff (please forgive me). But in case anyone else is interested in learning more about that, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement.

Comment: @ben unlike what has been stated if `htmlFor` is the react attribute instead of `for` it might not be for consistency matters but because `for` is a reserved word in Javascript (and React uses Javascript to render). At least this is the reason stated by the [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor](official documentation)

Comment: Another difference that should be stated in this correct answer, is the `htmlFor` value has to include the `#` sign along with the ID... Opposed to the html attribute `for`.

Comment: I wish they named it `forName`, following `className` naming convention

Comment: The more logical answer which available on official docs :- Since for is a reserved word in JavaScript, React elements use htmlFor instead.
Here is the link :-https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor

Answer (score 84):

Yes, for react,

`for` becomes `htmlFor`

`class` becomes `className`

etc.

see full list of how HTML attributes are changed here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 23):

For React you must use it's per-define keywords to define html attributes.

> `class` -> `className`

is used and

> `for` -> `htmlFor`

is used, as react is case sensitive make sure you must follow small and capital as required.

Answer (score 16):

## just using react `htmlFor` to replace `for`!

> Since `for` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, React elements use `htmlFor` instead.

### refs

you can find more info by following the below links.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8483

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1819

Answer (score 11):

both `for` and `class` are reserved words in JavaScript this is why when it comes to HTML attributes in JSX you need to use something else, React team decided to use `htmlFor` and `className` respectively

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with that. The JSX transformation could just translate it to 'class' which is also valid for property names. In fact, in Preact, you can use both class and className.

Comment: While React could transform it in JSX, it doesn't. Their docs (as of 25-Mar-2020) state "Since `for` is a reserved word in JavaScript, React elements use `htmlFor` instead.": https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor

Comment: @MalteR you can tell it to IE8, IE7 and IE6

Answer (score 3):

That is htmlFor in JSX and class is className in JSX