# React-js ignores label's 'for' attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that for 'class' we must use className, but how do i get react to preserve 'for' attribute?

The following:

```
<label for="recipient-name" className="control-label">Recipient:</label>
```

is rendered as:

```
<label class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
```

on an unrelated note, i find it annoying that i can not change attributes using chrome's console when using React.  is there a way around that?  for example if i inspect the rendered element and add the 'for' attribute manually, it disappears when i click away from that control (presumably because react re-renders the control i'm guessing)

Comment: Re unrelated note: That's just how it is. React controls the DOM, not something on the outside. Also have a look at the docs, where it is explained what to use instead of `for`: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes

Comment: Naturally this is because of reserved words in javascript.  `for` is a reserved word and so cannot be used as a json key, which is what the jsx parser is turning your jsx attribute names into.  Same reason it's `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React label element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752116/react-label-element)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You must use `htmlFor` attribute instead

```
<label htmlFor="recipient-name" className="control-label">Recipient:</label>
```

Answer (score 7):

`for` is a keyword in javascript so in JSX you can't use it. You must use `htmlFor` which is translated into `for` attribute once it is rendered to the DOM.