# label "for" is not being displayed in the frontend

Tags: forms, reactjs

I am trying to set for in label , however the react engine is ignoring it. (I am probably doing it wrong )

Can someone help me with correct syntax for using "for" in label for JSX.

Here is my code snippet

```
<form role="form">
    <div className="checkbox checkbox-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" className="styled" id="checkbox1" name="foambox" ref="foambox" />
          <label for="checkbox1"><span style={{margin:10,cursor:'default'}}>For this delivery, would you like us to   take back the foam box </label>
    </div>
 </form>
```

What is the correct way to specify it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React label element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752116/react-label-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlFor` is the proper syntax as you can see in [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes)

> All attributes are camel-cased and the attributes class and for are className and htmlFor, respectively, to match the DOM API specification.