# React radio input issue

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the following JSX code.  When I add the 'Yes' and 'No' text to complement the radio buttons, I get the following error...

```
 <tr>
    <td>Do you want the questions displayed in a random order?</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="random">Yes</input></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="random">No</input></td>
 </tr>
```

Error:
input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, the `<table>` element is used to represent *tabular data*. What you have here **isn't** tabular data.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a bunch of questions lined up in rows and columns for text questions and then inputs.  Would you recommend using a bunch of div tags in the place of a table, or some other method?

Answer (score 3):

Use `label`

```
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="yes" name="random"/>
```

Comment: using a label works, but I get the following warning:  "warning.js?0260:36 Warning: Unknown DOM property for. Did you mean htmlFor?"

Comment: This sheds some light on the issue, in case anyone cares.  Apparently, the 'for' keyword is a no-no for the React DOM...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752116/react-label-element