# I'm getting an error using React: "Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple CRUD app using React for my front-end, and I'm having trouble with this error:

```
app.js:21988 Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
```

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Add extends Component {

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state={
            blogs_name:''

        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                     <div className="form-group">
                        <label for="blogs_name">Title</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            id="blogs_name" 
                            value={this.state.blogs_name} 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I assume that it has to do something with the `for` property in my label.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React ignores 'for' attribute of the label element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752116/react-ignores-for-attribute-of-the-label-element)

Answer (score 109):

When using React, you can't use the `for` keyword in JSX, since that's a javascript keyword (remember, JSX is javascript so words like `for` and `class` can't be used because they have some other special meaning!)

To circumvent this, React elements use `htmlFor` instead (see [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor) for more information).

So, your `render` function should be (I only replaced `for` with `htmlFor`):

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="blogs_name">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="blogs_name" 
                        value={this.state.blogs_name} 
                    onChange={this.onChangeBlogsName} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Easy explanation!

Answer (score 23):

Replace `for=""` with `htmlFor=""`

In your case change this

```
<label for="blogs_name">Title</label>
```

To this

```
<label htmlFor="blogs_name">Title</label>
```

Answer (score 7):

`for` is a reserved word in JavaScript this is why when it comes to HTML attributes in JSX you need to use something else, React team decided to use `htmlFor` respectively. You can check the list of attributes from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Answer (score -6):

Short answer, Remove

```
for="blogs_name"
```

In your case.