# function keyword in class based component and inChange event

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-class-based-component

Can anyone please help me understand if there's any issue with the below code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class AddContactForm extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            number: ""
        }
    }

    handleOnChange(event) {
        console.log("Hi");
        console.log(event.target.id);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="mx-auto">
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="emailId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailId" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary w-25">Add</button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```

I am facing the problems below:

1 - unable to use function keyword with `handleOnChange` method

2 - none of my inputs are firing the `onChange` event. I am unable to get any logs in the console as added in `HandleOnChange` method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor bind all the methods.

```
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
         name: "",
         email: "",
         number: ""
     }
      this.handleOnChange: this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
   }
```

And in your inputs use like this
`<input onClick={this.handleOnChange} />`

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors in your code aside from the one @Muhammad pointed out, some attribute names were altered in to avoid conflict for jsx so:

1. `class` became `className`
2. `for` became `htmlFor` with the label element a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924585/im-getting-error-using-laravel-and-react-invalid-dom-property-for-did-you-m).

It's also worth noting that, using arrow function is [favored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-in-javascript-or-for-react-onclick) over using `bind`, so you create the function normally as an arrow function.

```js
handleOnChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Hi");
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log(event.target.value);  
};
```

and make `onChange` call it.

```js
onChange={this.handleOnChange}
```

You can refer for this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-pond-tr5c4?file=/src/test.jsx) for a demo, you may also want to read these two questions here:

1. [correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react)
2. [how-to-avoid-bind-or-inline-arrow-functions-inside-render-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-bind-or-inline-arrow-functions-inside-render-method)